# Overload cin to take ifstream instead of char* fname?

Tags: c++

I am trying to create a file manipulator so when I `cin >> filename` it will read the file and cout the value... of course I am going add more stuffs but I would like to proceed with the basic of getting the content of the file.

What I wanna achieve is by cout prompting user for a textfile name, then when he enter, I will do another `cin >> readfile` on next line of code then the compiler will run the operator overload and cout the content.

How do I achieve it. Below is my code.

Question is instead of taking in `char* fname`, can I send ifstream in instead

so I can do something like

```
ifstream infile(filename.c_str());
cin >> infile
```

Below is my current code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include "point2d.cpp"
#include "line2d.cpp"
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

struct myself
{
    string myname;
};

istream &operator>> (istream &stream, myself &myself )
{
    cout << "Enter my name";
    stream >> myself.myname;
    return stream;
}

istream &operator>> (istream &in, char* fname)
{
    ifstream inFile;
    inFile.open(fname);
    char ch1;
    while (inFile.get(ch1))
    {
        cout << ch1;
    }
}

int main()
{
    string filename;
    cout << "Enter file name: ";
    cin >> filename;

    // was thinking of
    // ifstream infile(filename.c_str());
    // then read infile with cin

    //how do i cin filename and read its content.     
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm confused. Do you just want to open a file whose name is provided by the user? That should be about four lines of code.

Comment: @KerrekSB I am trying to do my own input manipulator to extract the input filename from user and then perform some computation.

Comment: I'm no less confused. I don't even know what that means.

Comment: "How do i cin filename?" `cin >> filename;` You already did that, didn't you?

Comment: @jrok , i did cin filename, but it don't read . filename is of string value now. how do i overload it so cin can read content of filename(the file)

Comment: @user1578897: you don't. read from the (in)file

Comment: cin won't read your file. It can't. It's an `istream` object tied to *console*. Like Karoly says, use appropriate operator>> on your ifstream object.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath what should i do to create my own input manipulator..

Comment: this is the same assignment or a different account. Ask your instructor to clarify, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are messing up some concepts here. Your question is so vague, I'm not convinced that you are clear on what you want to do.

As far as I understand, you want

```
cin >> istream;
```

To do the following:

- Read a file name
- Open the file for reading
- replace `cin` with the input stream for the file

Is that correct?

IMHO this is a bad idea, because by conventions `cin >>` should **not modify `cin` in any significant manner**. Sure, it will advance the stream, and there are hacks to change the parsing mode.

**If you replace the stream with a new stream, make this *obvious*, don't try to hide it in some `>>` construct**.

Programming is not a sport of saving characters. Your program won't be faster if you make it more cryptic. Good programmers *write code that is very clear on what it does*, to avoid errors, and make it easier to find them.

```
istream* input = &cin; // Default input is stdin
*input >> filename; // read filename
input = new istream(filename, istream::in);
// Continue to use *input

// Clean up input, if you replaced it:
// You might want to use a boolean flag instead of this hack.
if (input != &cin) {
    delete input;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid you are quite confused here. `cin` does not read anything; you read from `cin`. So you might want to overload operator `>>` somehow to read the contents of `cin` into a file, but not the other way around.

What you can do is overload operator `<<` so it outputs the contents of a file into an output stream, such as `cout`. The following, nevertheless, is invalid:

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, char* filename);
```

You cannot define this operator because it is already defined. You need to write a class that represents a file name and overload the operator on that. A simple version:

```
struct Filename
{
  Filename(const string& filename) : filename_(filename) {}
  string filename_;
};

ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, const Filename& name)
{
  // read the file whose name is name.filename_
}
```

And you can call it this way:

```
cout << Filename("filename.ext");
```

Answer (score 0):

You are doing several bad practices all at once.

First, `cin` is an istream, so you are looking to overload an `istream` operator to take an `istream`.  That will be incredibly confusing for anyone trying to read your code.

Second, a function should do 1 job (that is, you should not try to hide functionality by lumping several distinct tasks into 1 function).  `istream` reads data from an input stream (in this case, the file name you want to open).  You will then need to pass that file name to an `ifstream` instance to actually read the file.  Presumably you want to output it, in which case you would use an `ostream` (e.g. `cout`).

The entire logic you are looking to implement can be done in roughly 5 lines of code or less:

```
string filename = "";
cin >> filename;
ifstream fin(filename.c_str(), ifstream::in);
copy(istreambuf_iterator<char>(fin), istreambuf_iterator<char>(), ostreambuf_iterator<char>(cout));
```

Which is much shorter and more readable than what you are trying to do.